# Show all records of a MySQL field in a Select HTML

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day, I am making a system for the university of the reservation of some mini-auditors, One (01) user can make several reservations and after booking the user must inform the payment by uploading a pdf.

To the user I show a form to inform the payment by uploading the pdf with the reservation number and the mini-audit, but if I have several reservations I need to show them all so that he selects which of all the reservations he made paid and wants to inform, as I have the code now only shows me the first reservation and I hope that when I click on the "select" HTML I will display all the reservation numbers that it has together with the mini-audit associated with that reservation. Then I leave the code (I apologize, I'm learning and I probably have many errors, Im sorry for my bad english too):

This is an example that how looks now https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkSPR.gif

```html
<?php
session_start();
 include '/login/funcs/funcs.php';
 include_once 'config.inc.php';
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
 
 $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
 
 
  
  $db=new Conect_MySql();
  $sql2 = "SELECT `idsolicitudes`, `id`, `nombre_sala` FROM solicitudes WHERE `id`=$idUsuario";
  $query2 = $db->execute($sql2);
  $datos=$db->fetch_row($query2);
  
  $sql3 = "SELECT `id`, `usuario`, `nombre`, `apellido` FROM usuarios WHERE `id`=$idUsuario";
  $query3 = $db->execute($sql3);
  $datos2=$db->fetch_row($query3);
  
   echo $datos['usuario'];
?>
 
 



<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->



<html>
  
  <?php


if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
    if ($nombre != "") {
        if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
            $descri= $_POST['descripcion'];
   $solicitud = $_POST ['solicitud'];
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_documentos(idsolicitud, id, titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo) VALUES('$solicitud','$idUsuario','$titulo','$descri','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')";
            $query = $db->execute($sql);
            if($query){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Buen trabajo!","Hemos recibido la información de tu pago, pero primero debemos confirmarla, espera por nuestro correo electrónico con información detallada!","success");';
    echo '}, 1000);</script>';
    
   /*
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">swal(\"Se guardó correctamente\");
    window.location.href='/login/welcome.php';
    </script>";*/
    
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>
  
<body>
  <div align="center" class="main"> <!-- Primer Div Parallax --> 
  <div class="container" id="stuff">
        <div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; style=background-color:white; padding: 30px;">
            <h2 id="stuff" style="background-color:#1c1c1c"><b>Informános tu pago</b></h2>
    <h4 ><b>Sube tu comprobante de deposito o transferencia solo despues de haber <a href="/login/reservar.php">reservado</a></b></h4>
            
   
   <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
    
     <div class="form-group">
                    <tr>
     
                        <td><label>Miniauditorio</label></td>
       
                        <td><div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="disabledSelect" name="titulo"  style="WIDTH: 228px; HEIGHT: 40px"  class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $datos['nombre_sala']; ?>">
       <option placeholder="<?php echo $datos['idsolicitud']; ?>"><?php echo $datos['nombre_sala']; ?></option>
       
        </select>
       </div>
      </td>
      </div>
                    </tr>
     </div>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><label><br />Nombre Titular</label></td>
                        <td><br /><input style="WIDTH: 250px; HEIGHT: 35px"  class="form-control" style="color:black" name="descripcion" disabled value="<?php echo $datos2['nombre']; ?> <?php echo $datos2['apellido']; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
     <img class="img2" src="/login/images/pdficon.png">
     <tr> 
                        <td><label><br />Número de Solicitud</label></td>
                        <td><div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="disabledSelect" name="titulo"  style="WIDTH: 228px; HEIGHT: 40px"  class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $datos['nombre_sala']; ?>">
       <option placeholder="<?php echo $datos['idsolicitud']; ?>"><?php echo $datos['idsolicitudes']; ?></option>
       
        </select>
                    </tr>
               
                        <td colspan="2"><br />
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      <input type="file" name="archivo"></td>
      </span>
      <div align="center">
      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="center"><br /><input align="center" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Subir" name="subir"></td>
                       <!-- <td><a href="lista.php">lista</a></td> -->
      
                    </tr>
     </div>
     
                </table>
    
    <h4><b>Antes de enviarnos su información, verifique que su archivo este guardado en formato PDF</b></h2>
            </form>            
        </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Posible imagen<img src="https://i.imgur.com/5utiwXU.jpg">-->
  
  
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my connection functions

```html
<?php 

class Conect_MySql {   
     var $obj = array ( "dbname" => "login",
                       "dbuser"  => "root"  ,
                       "dbpwd"  => ""  ,
                       "dbhost"  => "localhost" );


     var $q_id ="";
     var $ExeBit ="";
     var $db_connect_id = "";
     var $query_count   = 0;
    private function connect(){
  $this->db_connect_id = mysqli_connect($this->obj['dbhost'],$this->obj['dbuser'],$this->obj['dbpwd'],$this->obj['dbname']);
             if (!$this->db_connect_id)
              {
                echo (" Error no se puede conectar al servidor:".mysqli_connect_error());
       }
  }

function execute($query) {       
        $this->q_id = mysqli_query($this->db_connect_id,$query);        
        if(!$this->q_id ) {
            $error1 = mysqli_error($this->db_connect_id);
            die ("ERROR: error DB.<br> No Se Puede Ejecutar La Consulta:<br> $query <br>MySql Tipo De Error: $error1");
            exit;
        }         
 $this->query_count++; 
 return $this->q_id;    
    }


  public function fetch_row($q_id = "") {
     if ($q_id == "") {
      $q_id = $this->q_id;
      }
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($q_id);
        return $result;
    } 

 public function get_num_rows() {
        return mysqli_num_rows($this->q_id);
    }

public function get_row_affected(){
    return mysqli_affected_rows($this->db_connect_id);
}

public function get_insert_id() {
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->db_connect_id);
}

public  function free_result($q_id) {
     if($q_id == ""){
      $q_id = $this->q_id;
  }
 mysqli_free_result($q_id);
    } 

public function close_db(){
        return mysqli_close($this->db_connect_id);
    }

public function more_result() {
  return mysqli_more_results($this->db_connect_id);
 }
public function next_result() {
  return mysqli_next_result($this->db_connect_id);
 }

  public function __construct(){
        $this->connect();
    }
  
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you duplicate the content of this post? What is `$db` creating, is `execute` your function or one of the native drivers?

Comment: Related to your title: 'Show all records of a MySQL field in a Select HTML'. 1. Did you create a variable with information from your dataabase? 2. you can var_dump this variable (which should be an array now). 3. What results do you get? If its empty, something went wrong. 4. if its not empty: echo $variable['key'], will show the value of that variable. is this what you need? i dont really understand

Comment: Hello Chris and Ronnie, i updated the post so i added the connction function and a gif (so you can see what that i can show now) I need to see all the reservation data when i clicked the option and i only see the first on the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqli_fetch_raw($results)
```

and

```
mysqli_fetch_array($results)
```

will give you information about only one raw. and use,

```
$datos = mysqli_fetch_all($query2)
```

you can get all output results by adding for loop.
for example.

if you want get all outputs,

```
    <select id="disabledSelect" name="titulo"  style="WIDTH: 228px; HEIGHT: 40px"  class="form-control">
<?php
    for ($i=0 ; $i<=(count($result)-1);$i++){
if ($i==0){$selected="select";} else {$selected=""}
    echo '<option value="'. $result[$i][0].'" '.$selected.'>'.$result[$i][2].'</option>';
    }
?php
</select>
```

sorry for my bad English too..

Comment: Excuse i'm rookie, how Will be the SQL statement   on my code?

Comment: Haven't time d. very sorry for it. Try for it. you will find a way. This answer will help you. change your `$datos`  to `$datos = mysqli_fetch_all($query2)` and `$datos2` to `$datos2 = mysqli_fetch_all($query3)`. Put above example with a simple edit in HTML SELECT tag.

Comment: Lol im terrible on this, dont know how to doit :/. Can you please edit my code?

Comment: I still dont know how to use this page, but i see no edition on my code :(

Comment: Sorry. It was my fault. I can't edit others questions on my pc. But i've edited my answer. replace your `$datos` and `SELECT` tag with my codes.